# (python) how to check changes between two strings like on e.g. text-compare.com

Tags: python, text, compare

I have two texts and want to print the text that was added
[image]
i have two variables x and y which are a string.
I would like it to look like this:

```
x = 'abcdefg'
y = 'abcdTHISefg'

print(TextCompare(x, y))

output:
> this
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparing two strings and returning the difference. Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30683463/comparing-two-strings-and-returning-the-difference-python-3)

Comment: the code that was sent there also shows me the text that follows the text I want to print, so no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are interested in finding what has been added between two strings then it seems like Python's [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html) might be of help.

For example, the following gives `this` as an output on your test data:

```py
import difflib

x = 'abcdefg'
y = 'abcdTHISefg'

diff = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, x, y)

for tag, x_start, x_end, y_start, y_end in diff.get_opcodes():
    if tag == 'insert':
        print(y[y_start:y_end].casefold())
```